# How do I use a REGEXMATCH, SUM, and ARRAYFORMULA in a code

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Some magic items grant extra bonuses therefore extra numbers, these 18 checks can't all fit in a grid and look nice. I put a data validation on the 18 checks and I have a grid of magic items that provide different bonuses. So what you do is you label the type of check then label the bonus. I'm using a REGEXMATCH, SUM, and an IF statement. The following code is just for 1 check.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(C3:C18,J2),SUM(REGEXMATCH(C3:C18,J2)),))
```

I need a code where If C3 = J2 then add D3 but I need that to be throughout C3:D18, that means I need the selected AC (dependent on J2) labeled cells in the c column, add their adjacent D column bonus then add them up

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure if I understood correctly, but maybe sumif() will work?

```
=sumif(C3:C18, J2, D3:D18)
```

Comment: Glad to hear and since you are new here, please check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I know but my rep is low and I can't vote up if it is below 15, it's 9

Comment: You don't need rep to accept an answer - you now have enough Rep to upvote answers anyway; it's helpful for both the community and the answerers if you accept answers that solved your question

Answer (score 1):

you can also do:

```
=SUM(FILTER(D3:D18, C3:C18=J2))
```